# making variable case insensitive from start.sh file in Java code

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I just need to make system variable in jboss server case insensitive.

variable is defined in start.sh file as below:

```
cd /opt/logs
nohup /opt/jboss/bin/standalone.sh -DmyEnvironment=Release_19.2.2_ST -c standalone-full_st.xml &
```

Below is the current code which  I am using to append the string with file name according to environment.

```
public static String getEnvConfiguredFile(String file) {
    String env = System.getProperty("myEnvironment");
    if(env !=null) {
        if(env.contains("AT")){
        return file+"_at";
        }
        else if(env.contains("ST")){
        return file+"_st";
        }
        else if(env.contains("PROD")){
        return file+"_prod";
        }
        else{
        return file;
        }
    }else {
    return file;
    }
}
```

The issue is when I am using -DmyEnvironment=Release_19.2.2_st(here st is in lowercase) I am getting application error because it is unable to find the file.

To run the run in lower case I changed the method to:

```
public static String getEnvConfiguredFile(String file) {
    String envtmp = System.getProperty("myEnvironment");
    env=envtmp.toUpperCase();
    if(env !=null) {
        if(env.contains("AT")){
        return file+"_at";
        }
        else if(env.contains("ST")){
        return file+"_st";
        }
        else if(env.contains("PROD")){
        return file+"_prod";
        }
        else{
        return file;
        }
    }else {
    return file;
    }
}
```

Tough the issue looks simple, but uppercase in start.sh is working fine and lowercase is giving error.

Below is the exception

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
        at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
        at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
        at com.corridor.util.PropertiesUtil.<init>(PropertiesUtil.java:22) [home-util.jar:]
        at com.corridor.util.PathUtil.getBrokerProperties(PathUtil.java:90) [home-util.jar:]
        at com.corridor.util.MessageUtil.<clinit>(MessageUtil.java:32) [home-util.jar:]
        ... 153 more
```

Comment: Can you provide the error messae as well? I also seem to remember that in certain cases properties could only be read with System.getenv() ... you might want to give this a try.

Comment: I don't understand your doubt. Strings in Java *are* case sensitive, and so are file names under *nix. You cannot change this behaviour. So, your solution is the good one. (well, you have still a bug on null checkings, you should check nulls before calling toUpperCase).

Comment: reading the property is not a problem, @second

Comment: the problem is when ST is in uppercase then only the if condition is working, otherwise it is returning filename without any append leading to null pointer exception

Comment: you should post the error message with full stack. The filename that you are looking for is **always** lowercase, right?

Comment: @luca.vercelli      argument of the method is filename. I am appending string according to environment. like property_st.txt or property_prod.txt. Here appending is failed due to which it is only returning property as file name which is not present on the server giving nullpointer exception. Added stack trace in my question

Comment: Judging from the Stacktrack (assuming the PropertiesUtil class is from you) you call the `java.util.Properties.load()` method with something that is null. Can you supply that code as well? Somewhere around there you should try to access the 'path' to the file. You should verify that it has the proper file destination.